# Use nfs to for default folder with vagrant

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

I want to migrate a big project (5000 files) to vagrant with virtualbox.
Virtualbox shared folders is known to be slow for big project, so I want to use NFS.

But, I don't find the right way to use NFS instead of the default shared folder issue. It works when I put code in another folder, and share it. But I want to integrate Vagrant in the current one.

```
config.vm.synced_folder '.', '/vagrant', nfs: true
```

doesn't work:

```
exportfs: duplicated export entries:
exportfs:   10.11.12.13:/home/vincent/workspace/gp
exportfs:   10.11.12.13:/home/vincent/workspace/gp
```

Any idea to solve this strange issue?

Thank you.

**Update 1**

Same error with these parameters

```
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", disabled: true
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/home/vagrant/gp", nfs: true
```

Here is the full error stack:

```
nfsd running
exportfs: duplicated export entries:
exportfs:   10.11.12.13:/home/vincent/workspace/gp
exportfs:   10.11.12.13:/home/vincent/workspace/gp
==> default: Mounting NFS shared folders...
Vagrant::Errors::LinuxNFSMountFailed: The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

mount -o 'vers=3,udp' 10.11.12.1:'/home/vincent/workspace/gp' /home/vagrant/gp

Stdout from the command:



Stderr from the command:

stdin: is not a tty
mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting 10.11.12.1:/home/vincent/workspace/gp
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to explicitly disable the default synced folder by adding the following line in your `Vagrantfile` so as to mount the NFS share to `/vagrant`

config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", disabled: true

After than do a `vagrant reload` and see if it works.

In addition, consider using `rsync` type synced folder for your use case, I think it works even better. See https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/rsync.html

Comment: Thank you for help.
I have the same error with these parameters:

     config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", disabled: true
     config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/home/vagrant/gp", nfs: true

Comment: Updated directly the question, and add the full error stack.

Comment: Using rsync was a good solution, since there's a bug with NFS used on the /vagrant folder (something like "nfsnohostip"). This is how I did in Vagrantfile:  

# Disable nfs for main folder because of nohostip issue. cf : https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/4192
`config.nfs.functional = false`  

`config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
    # Disable virtualbox shared folder: really slow with 1000+ files. Use nfs or rsync instead
    v.functional_vboxsf = false
end`

To have a real-time synced folder with rsync, use : `vagrant rsync-auto`

Comment: RSync saved my life too. Just added `config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", type: "rsync", rsync__exclude: ".git/"` to my Vagrantfile. Please also note that `rsync__auto` is set to `true` by default in Vagrant.

Answer (score 0):

You can also get this error message if you are trying to create a vm in a directory above another previously created vm. You will need to destroy the the vm's in each sub-directory.